# How to extract a page out of a QPdfDocument without it being converted to a QImage

Tags: qt, pdf, merge

I would like to combine several PDF documents into one so that I don't have to search each individual document for a specific word.

As a development environment, I use the Qt Creator, and would like to solve this with Qt. I already wrote some code, but I used the `QPdfDocument::render` function, which only outputs an image, which is copied to the merged PDF. That's why I can't search for words in the merged PDF document.

```cpp
void mergePDFs(const QStringList& fileList, const QString& outputFileName) {
    QPdfWriter pdfWriter(outputFileName);
    pdfWriter.setResolution(150);


    QPdfDocument firstFilePDF;
    firstFilePDF.load(fileList.first());
    QPageSize pageSize = QPageSize(firstFilePDF.pagePointSize(1).toSize());
    pdfWriter.setPageSize(pageSize);
    firstFilePDF.close();

    QPainter painter(&pdfWriter);

    foreach(const QString& file, fileList) {
        QPdfDocument pdfDocument;
        pdfDocument.load(file);

        for(int i = 0; i < pdfDocument.pageCount(); i++) {

            QPdfDocumentRenderOptions renderOptions = QPdfDocumentRenderOptions();
            renderOptions.setRenderFlags(QPdfDocumentRenderOptions::RenderFlag::Annotations);

            QPageSize pageSize = QPageSize(pdfDocument.pagePointSize(i).toSize());
            pdfWriter.setPageSize(pageSize);

            QSize scaledSize = pdfDocument.pagePointSize(i).toSize()*=(2);
            QImage image = pdfDocument.render(i, scaledSize);
            painter.drawImage(QPoint(0, 0), image);

            pdfWriter.newPage();
        }
        pdfDocument.close();
    }
    painter.end();
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {


    QApplication app(argc, argv);


    QMessageBox selectFilesMsg;
    selectFilesMsg.setText("Please select your files");
    selectFilesMsg.exec();

    QStringList files;
    QFileDialog dialog = QFileDialog();
    dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog::ExistingFiles);
    dialog.setNameFilter("PDF Files (*.pdf)");
    if (dialog.exec()) {
        files = dialog.selectedFiles();
        if (files.isEmpty()) {
            QMessageBox emptyFile;
            emptyFile.setText("The file you wanted to open is empty");
            emptyFile.exec();
            return 0;
        }
    } else {
        QMessageBox canceledMsg;
        canceledMsg.setText("The process has been canceled by the user");
        canceledMsg.exec();
        return 0;
    }

    QString outputFileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(nullptr, "Save Merged PDF", QDir::homePath(), "PDF Files (*.pdf)");
    if (outputFileName.isEmpty()) {
        QMessageBox emptyFile;
        emptyFile.setText("The file you wanted to save is empty");
        emptyFile.exec();
        return 0;
    }

    mergePDFs(files, outputFileName);


    QMessageBox finishedMsg;
    finishedMsg.setText("The Merge has been completed");
    finishedMsg.exec();

    return app.exec();
}
```